# Sticky UITableView header like App Store Featured page in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

How do I imitate this behavior in UITableView. Wherein, if I pull the table DOWN, the header sticks at the stop, but if I scroll the table UP, the header goes with it.

Like the app store.
**(scrolling up)**
[image]

**(scrolling down)**
[image]

Comment: Hey have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tableHeaderView` for this type of work.

In your `viewDidLoad` write below code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

**// Take one view and subview that view in the tableview.**

    UIView *viewsearch=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,-10, 320,83)];
    [self.Yourtablename addSubview:viewsearch];


**//Now take any controls which you want to show in your header. e.x label,button,searchbar**

UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[lbl1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,100,20)];
lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lbl1.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
lbl1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;    
[viewsearch addSubview:lbl1];
lbl1.text= @"BUY THE NEW APPLE TV FROM THE APPSTORE";

**//Here is the code.With the help of this code  when you scroll UP the headerview hide.**


       self.tbluser.tableHeaderView = viewsearch;
        self.tbluser.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(viewsearch.frame));
        }
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I just went online today. I'll try this solution tonight and let you know